# Photodiode and Phototransistor circuit

Tags: photodiode, phototransistor

How can I design a circuit that characterizes photodiodes and phototransistors (as output/input)? That circuit should communicate electronically over an isolated link where one side runs a low voltage system and runs a high voltage on the other

Comment: What do you want to characterize about the photodiodes or phototransistors?

Comment: photodiodes and phototransistors are both sensors (input devices)

Comment: Do you want to do this with discrete components? You can achieve this with an opto-isolator see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opto-isolator